# Allow web spiders access restricted pages in Symfony

Tags: symfony, web-crawler, symfony-security

How to allow access to restricted pages in Symfony to web crawlers?

I think it should be allowed by a list of IPs, but how to authenticate them?

Comment: Why are these pages restricted then? Seems a bit contradictory. What do they need to crawl?

Comment: The pages are for users, but we need that web crawler could acces a part of them if they have ROLE_CRAWLER.

Comment: Google will penalize you or even delist your pages if you are showing GoogleBot different content than anonymous users. If you are interested in setting up a paywall for (news) content, check https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40543?rd=1